# Why are Dunnett's p-values smaller than those from two-sample t-tests?

Tags: multiple-comparisons

Since Dunnett corrects for multiple comparisons I would assume the p-value would always be higher than a direct two-sample t-test.  I came across a situation where this was not the case.  Possible reasons why?

Example:

```
library(multcomp)
a1=data.frame(group=rep(c('a','b','control','d'),each=3),
              y=c(13.3,13.8,13.6,10.9,14.4,11.1,18.8,15.2,16.6,1.6,1.2,.9))
a1$group=relevel(a1$group,ref='control')
fit=aov(y~group,data=a1)
summary(fit)
test.dunnett=glht(fit,linfct=mcp(group="Dunnett"))
summary(test.dunnett)


t.test(a1$y[a1$group=='control'],a1$y[a1$group=='a'])$p.value
t.test(a1$y[a1$group=='control'],a1$y[a1$group=='b'])$p.value
t.test(a1$y[a1$group=='control'],a1$y[a1$group=='d'])$p.value
```

Output:

```
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
group        3  413.0  137.67   74.99 3.37e-06 ***
Residuals    8   14.7    1.84         


 Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Multiple Comparisons of Means: Dunnett Contrasts


Fit: aov(formula = y ~ group, data = a1)

Linear Hypotheses:
                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
a - control == 0   -3.300      1.106  -2.983  0.04298 *  
b - control == 0   -4.733      1.106  -4.279  0.00704 ** 
d - control == 0  -15.633      1.106 -14.131  < 0.001 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
(Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)

[1] 0.08504438
[1] 0.03780491
[1] 0.00342318
```

The Dunnett p-values (.04, .007, .001) are smaller compared to the t-test p-values (.085, .038, .003).

Comment: A mistake.  The names are quite similar.

Comment: Okay. I thought maybe so, but didn't want to edit in case it was a deliberate choice.

Comment: Note that the first t-test p-value is smaller if you set the option `var.equal = TRUE` (and maybe the third as well).